# Why we need Reflection at all?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection, system.reflection

I was studying Reflection, I got some of it but I am not getting everything related to this concept. Why do we need Reflection? What things we couldn't achieve that we need Reflection?

Comment: one case is...if you want to create an object based upon a string.

Comment: I'm writing something good to give you examples. I have been using reflection for almost my life as programmer.

Comment: With threading, generics and events (listeneters, eventbus, c# events, observable etc) you can create frameworks that will reduce you code to the business feature only.

Comment: Just an example: imagine you have a class with a 1000 attributes and you have a method clear (private void clear()).

Comment: It is supposed to get all primitive int, short, double and set 0, types Integer, Short, Double, Boolean, String and set null

Comment: Can you imagine the amout of code you need to write? With reflection you write less code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many, many scenarios that reflection enables, but I group them primarily into two buckets.

- Reflection enables us to write code that *analyzes other code*.

Consider for example the most basic question about an assembly: what types are in it?  Assemblies are *self-describing* and reflection is the mechanism by which that description is surfaced to other code.

Suppose for example you wanted to write a program which took an assembly and did a graphical display of the relationships between the various classes in that assembly, to help you understand that code.  There are such tools. They're in Visual Studio.  **Someone wrote those tools.** They did not appear by magic.  Reflection is the mechanism designed into the .NET framework that enables you or me or anyone else to write tools that understand code.

- Reflection enables us to move compile time bindings to runtime.

Suppose you have a static method `Foo.Bar()`.  When you put a call to `Foo.Bar()` in your program, you know with 100% certainty that the method you think is going to be called is actually going to be called.  We call static methods "static" because the binding from the name Bar to the code that gets called can be understood *statically* -- that is, without running the program.

Now consider a virtual method `Blah()` on a base class.  When you call `whatever.Blah()` you don't know exactly which `Blah()` will be called at compile time, but you know that *some* method `Blah()` with no arguments will be called on *some* type that is the runtime type of `whatever`, and that type is equal to or derived from the type which declares `Blah()`.  (In fact you know more: you know that it is equal to or derived from the compile time type of `whatever`.)  Virtual binding is a form of dynamic binding, but it is not *fully* dynamic. There's no way for the user to decide that this call should be to a different method on a different type hierarchy.

Reflection enables us to make calls that are bound *entirely* at runtime, based *entirely* on user choices if we like. We pay a performance penalty, and we lose compile-time type safety, but we gain the flexibility to decide 100% at runtime what code we call. There are scenarios where that's a reasonable tradeoff.

Answer (score 5):

Reflection is such a deep part of the .NET framework that you often don't know that you're doing it (see Attributes and LINQ for instance).  And when you do know you're doing it, even if it feels wrong, it might be the only way to achieve a particular objective.

Apart from the two broad areas that Eric mentioned here are a few others.  There are lots more, these are just some that come to mind immediately.

#### Serialization (and similar)

Whether you're using XML or JSON or rolling your own, serializing objects is much easier when you don't have to write specific code for each class to enable serialization.  Reflection enables you to enumerate the properties in your object that have been flagged for (or not flagged against) serailization and write them to the output.

This isn't about saving state though.  Reflection allows us to write generic methods that can produce business output too, like CSV or XLSX files from an arbitrary collection.  I get a lot of mileage out of my `ToCSV(...)` and `ToExcel(...)` extensions for things like producing downloadable versions of data sets on my web-based reporting.

#### Accessing Hidden Data

Yes, I know, this is a dodgy one.  And yeah, Eric is probably going to slap me for this, but...

There's a lot of code out there - I'm looking at you, ASP.NET - that hides interesting and useful stuff behind `private` or `protected`.  Sometimes the only way to get them out is to use reflection.  Sometimes it's not the only way, but it can be the *simpler* way.

#### Attributes

Every time you tag an `Attribute` onto one of your classes, methods, etc. you are implicitly providing data that is going to be accessed through reflection. Want to use those attributes yourself?  Reflection is the only way you can get at them.

#### LINQ and Other Expressions

This is really important stuff these days.  If you've ever used LINQ to SQL, Entity Frameworks, etc. then you've used `Expression` in some way.  You write a simple little POCO to represent a row in your database table and everything else gets handled by reflection.  When you write a predicate expression the system is using the reflection model to build structures that are then processed (visited) to build an SQL statement.

Expressions aren't just for LINQ either, you do some really interesting things yourself, once you know what you're doing.  I have code to generate line parsers for CSV import that run pretty damn quickly when compiled to `Func<string, TRecord>`.  These days I tend to use a mapper somebody else wrote, but at the time I needed to slice a few more % off the total import time for a file with 20K records that was uploaded to a website periodically.

#### P/Invoke Marshalling

This one is a big deal behind the scenes and occasionally in the foreground too.  When you want to call a Windows API function or use a native DLL, P/Invoke gives you ways to achieve this without having to mess about with building memory buffers in both directions.  The marshalling methods use reflection to do translation of certain things - strings and so on being the obvious example - so that you don't have to get your hands dirty.  All based on the `Type` object that is the foundation of reflection.

---

Fact is, without reflection the .NET framework wouldn't be what it is.  No `Attribute`s, no `Expression`s, probably a lot less interop between the languages.  No automatic marshalling.  No LINQ... at least in the way we often use it now.